# Mass VirtualHost in vhost.conf help

Tags: virtualhost

I'm trying to set up a service where clients can sign up and a subdomain will be automatically made for them as part of their account.

After looking high and low on google i came onto an apache page detialing Mass Virtualhost and similar solutions.

My problem is that I can't make heads or tails from the examples and i'm not sure how it all works.

The end result i want `www` to be always pointing to `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs` while `*`.domain.com always points to `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/members`

is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want http://awesomesauce.domain.com to go to /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/awesomesauce ? Try it like this:

Put this in `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/conf/vhost.conf`

```
ServerAlias *.domain.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com
RewriteCond /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: would i need to remove my A record that points *.domain.com to my host IP?

Comment: No, it's just fine :-)